# Popup covering screen, text underneath selectable

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you click anywhere on the page, a popup goes up. That popup covers the screen, but if you click it three times the last `p` element gets selected.

How can I prevent this?

*PS: I use JQuery in this example for simple click events but not in the real application. I would prefer a solution without JQuery (plain JS is okay)*

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  $('.popup').show();
});

$('.popup').on('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popupContent').on('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display:none;
  
  position:fixed;
  
  top:0;
  left:0;
  
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.popupContent {  
  position:absolute;
  
  left:10%;
  top:10%;
  
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popupContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Selecting is not the same as clicking.

Comment: @Roberrrt Sounds legit, but I don't know how that comment helps me out here. Do you mean I should do something else instead of `stopPropagation`?

Comment: stopPropagation disables the clickthrough, but not the selecting, I do have a suggestion you can use, one moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my testing, all you need to do is add some text to the popup itself.

Easily verifiable by deleting all of the text from something well established and tested such as the [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). The same thing happens when it is emptied.

It must have something to do with selecting the nearest text node if none exist within the element. Because, as you may note, it selects the closest paragraph in your example.

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  $('.popup').show();
});

$('.popup').on('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  $('.popup').hide();
});

$('.popupContent').on('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display:none;
  
  position:fixed;
  
  top:0;
  left:0;
  
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.popupContent {  
  position:absolute;
  
  left:10%;
  top:10%;
  
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popupContent">test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if you triple click on a text

Comment: Okay this amazes me a little. Thank you!

Comment: @NathanP. What browser do you use?

Comment: @Randy Chrome 57

Comment: @NathanP. I see what you mean, but I don't think thats undesirable.

Comment: @Randy Ok ! I may have misunderstood your problem so :P

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to add `user-select: none` on the `p` element.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/s8zm6L37/

Comment: Although this would work, it's not desirable if the popup is closed and would be a lot of work to actively enable and disable.

Comment: I do not know how complex your application is, but you could add a class on the wrapper div when the popup is enabled. Then in your CSS only add the ```user-select: none``` when this class is set on the wrapper.

Comment: Great solution for other situations, but the above is just a little better ;)

Comment: No problem, happy to help.